# CentOS 7 / PHP 7: Can only reach site by IP

Tags: php, centos, redhat

PHP 7 / CentOS 7

I've been having trouble finding instructions for this.   I've setup PHP 7.3.7 on CentOS 7.   Everything is working fine.   However, I can only reach PHP pages by IP and not be URL.

Works Fine:
http://10.0.0.5/test.php

Does not work
http://mysite.aaa.com/test.php

From another computer on the same neetwork, I can ping mysite.aaa.com fine.   Most all of the guides I've found on installing PHP on CentOS stop at a point where you first hit a test PHP page using the IP address.   I might be missing keywords to use to correctly Google search for this.

I did already get URL rewrites working to remove the ".php" extension from the URL's.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does `mysite.aaa.com` point to `10.0.0.5`? What Webserver are you using? Have you configured your vHost to listen to `mysite.aaa.com`?

Comment: Your other machine likely has the local IP added to your host file? Do the same in centos by adding the ip and domain to /etc/hosts - Or if you expect the address to be on a public (or private) DNS, check that it's not an issue with the DNS on the CentOS machine. If you're outside of php, from the command line can you use something like "wget http://mysite.aaa.com/test.php" and does it return the correct data? If that also fails, check /etc/resolv.conf and add "nameserver 8.8.8.8"